# Node.js code only working at top of file with sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

When at the top of my server-side code, this works fine and the results produced are correct:

```
var data_playlists = {};

models.Playlist.findAll({
attributes: ['id', 'name']
 }).then(function (playlists){
  data_playlists['playlists'] = playlists.map(function(playlist){
  return playlist.get({plain: true})
});
addsongs(data_playlists, 1);
addsongs(data_playlists, 2);
addsongs(data_playlists, 3);

});
```

but when it's inside one of my Express methods, it isn't functioning properly; particularly, the addsongs method is not working as it should.

```
function addsongs(playlist_object, id_entered){
 var arraysongs = [];

 models.Playlist.findOne({
      attributes: ['id'],
      where: {
          id: id_entered
      }
  })
  .then(function(playlist) {
      playlist.getSongs().then(function (thesongs){
        for(var k = 0; k < thesongs.length ; k++){
          arraysongs.push(thesongs[k].Songs_Playlists.SongId);
        }
        playlist_object.playlists[(id_entered - 1)]['songs'] = arraysongs;
      });
  });
}
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why it works when the top segment of code is at the top, but doesn't work when inside my app.get() call.

Comment: Can you also share code for app.get() call?

Comment: @TusharArora app.get('/api/playlists', function(request, response){
  response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    response.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(data_playlists));
});

Comment: Where is the call to addSongs function?

Comment: @TusharArora at the bottom of the file.

Comment: **"but when it's inside one of my Express methods, it isn't functioning properly"** add the code right from the route to your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I have conducted that you want to return playlists (`id` and `name`) together with their songs (`id`). First of all your code will not work because the calls of `addsongs(data_playlists, id)` are run before `data_playlists` is filled with data by code above it. Moreover, the `addsongs` function performs asynchronous operations returning Promises, so calling them one by one will not give expected result. I suppose you can do it completely differently.

I suggest you use `include` attribute of `options` object that can be passed to `findAll()` method. `include` says which association model you also want to return from current query. In this case you want to return playlists together with their songs (M:M relation according to your code), so you need to include `Song` model in the query.

```
function getPlaylistsWithSongs() {
    return models.Playlist.findAll({
        attributes: ['id', 'name'],
        include: [
            {
                model: models.Song,
                as: 'Songs', // depends on how you have declare the association between songs and playlists
                attributes: ['id'],
                through: { attributes: [] } // prevents returning fields from join table
            }
        ]
    }).then((playlistsWithSongs) => {
        return playlistsWithSongs;
    });
}
```

Example result of `getPlaylistsWithSongs` result would be (after translating it to JSON e.g. like `playlistsWithSongs.toJSON()`)

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'playlist #1',
        Songs: [
            { id: 1 },
            { id: 2 }
        ]
    }
]
```

Above code returns all `playlists` (their `id` and `name`) with their `songs` (only their `id`). Now in your route resolver you can simply call above function to return the result

```
app.get('/api/playlists', function (request, response) {
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    getPlaylistsWithSongs().then(function(playlistsWithSongs){
        response.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(playlistsWithSongs));
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

In order to simply return array of IDs instead array of objects with id (`songs`), you need to map the result. There is no simple sequelize way to return array of IDs in such a case.

```
}).then((playlistWithSongs) => {
    let jsonPlaylists = playlistsWithSongs.map((singlePlaylist) => {
        // return JSON representation of each playlist record
        return singlePlaylist.toJSON();
    });

    jsonPlaylists.forEach((playlist) => {
        // at every playlist record we map Songs to array of primitive numbers representing it's IDs
        playlist.songs = playlist.Songs.map((song) => {
            return song.id;
        });

        // when we finish we can delete the Songs property because now we have songs instead
        delete playlist.Songs;
    });

    console.log(jsonPlaylists);
    // example output: [{ id: 1, name: 'playlist #1', songs: [1, 2, 3] }]
    return jsonPlaylists;
});
```

Comment: Each song is just an integer (without id) and since it's belongsToMany, would that change anything for the model/attributes? There wouldn't be any attributes in that case, correct? The 'through' table in the relationship is Songs_Playlists

Comment: There still need to be attributes because otherwise it would not return any fields of `Song` model. I have updated the answer to show you how to do it. You must `map` the result to replace array of objects with array of IDs